# How to trigger a Logic App from ACR Task?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-container-registry, acr

Is there any way to trigger a Logic App after a successful ACR task run like a custom connector or a webhook?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, this is possible since the Azure Logic App are allowed to be triggered using web hooks.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/create-webhook-trigger

And you can configure the webhook on the ACR using

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr/webhook?view=azure-cli-latest#az-acr-webhook-create

The Webhook requires a URL and you define which actions on the Acrylic's will trigger the webhook to be triggered.